# How can I run app when it is killed?

Tags: cordova, plugins

This plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode works if the app is in the background.
But, if I kill the app in background it doesn't work.
Is there a way to run the app when it is killed?
I need to receive a local notification when the app is killed.